# Solaris Security and Id's

Tags: security

On a Solaris machine I need to transfer files from windows to unix server as well as server to server. Is there a way to get the oracle id permissions (uid gid) when I do this here is an example :

My id Brian using winscp transfers a file to my unix server DBserv1 to directory /u04/oradata/hrspec 
Files have the following

```
-rw-r--r--   1 oracle   orainst   573440 Jul 20  2010 system_01.dbf
```

Right now I would have to copy the file then change chmod to 655 then chown to oracle.

Logging in with the oracleid is not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but you should probably use `tar` or `rsync` to be able to preserve UID, GID and permissions during a file transfer.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `scp` command, new files inherit your uid and gid. You can use something like this to preserve owner:

```
/usr/sfw/bin/gtar -cpvf - system_01.dbf  | \
     ssh root@172.16.138.15 "/usr/sfw/bin/gtar -xp -C /u04/oradata/hrspec "
```

or you can use POSIX ACLs.